# Need to handle post request and redirect the user to a specific website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I need to test redirect post request to a specific website. I have created the controller methods in ASP.net webapi and hosted it in IIS. I am trying to call the URL via post man and do get status 200 OK message. I need to ensure that http://test.com gets called. How do I ensure that.

I am using the URL http://ehr.com/api/redirect as POST request in POSTMAN.

```
public class RedirectController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://test.com");
        return response;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        string result = "Hello world";
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        resp.Content = new StringContent(result, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
        return resp;
    }

}
```

I need a webapi hosted on the controller to load websites with get request when called from a thirdparty vendor website. Our third party vendor website calls the website URL with the post method. So what I am trying to achieve is creating an intermediary website that host the API. I shall ask the vendor website to point to that API website which accept the post method and redirect to the correct website with get method. The vendor website are unable to change their request from post to get as they are using it via HTTPS protocal and for security reason use only POST request

Comment: I suggest you [edit] the additional details from the comment you posted. That way those trying to help you have a better picture of the actual problem and not see this as an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I am not sure what more information is required . I am aiming to achieve  What I have mentioned above . I need test locally by creating a webapi and hosting it on IIS. That webapi should be able to accept POST request and redirect to a any site that is mentioned there. The question is how do I test it?